# Remove duplicate attachments

Tags: attachments

Here is the situation:
I have an automated script that upload attachments and link each attachment to a specific post. By mistake, the script run multiple times and I have the following

1. More than one attachment post in the Media library for a single file (the different attachment posts have the same File URL).
2. One of these attachment is actually attached to the post.

What I want to do is obviously is clean up the media library. I need to remove the attachment post without removing the file, and also make sure that I don't remove the ones that are actually attached to their posts.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you take a look at [this search results](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bduplicate+%2Battachments+is%3Aquestion) and see if you find relevant information to add to the Question?

Comment: @brasofilo I checked the previous questions with Google. I didn't find anything which relates specifically to my problem.

Comment: In the media library you can sort by the "Attached to" column.  Can you not sort and then bulk delete all the un-attached items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function get_attachment_files(){
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => 0
);
$attachments = get_posts($args);
 if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        wp_delete_post( $post->ID );
    }
 }
}
add_action('admin_init','get_attachment_files');
```

adapted from: http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/list-all-unattached-files-in-media-library/

I'd be careful of this though, because I am not sure it won't delete the images too.  In fact, I think it will, but I am throwing it out there as fodder and not as a perfect solution.

If you dig into `wp_delete_attachment` there is a filter called `wp_delete_file` that you might be able to use to trick the function into deleting files from a made-up directory, ie *not* deleting your actual files, but I can't be certain.